# How to read from a mio TcpStream with a timeout?

Tags: rust, mio

I'm using [Mioco](https://github.com/dpc/mioco). `mio::net::tcp::TcpStream` does not implement `Clone`, so it seems that it's not possible to share a `TcpStream` across multiple threads/coroutines (or if it is possible, I'm not sure how; I'm pretty new to Rust). I've hence assumed that for simultaneous reading/writing to a single `TcpStream`, it's necessary to use a single coroutine to do both the reading and writing.

In order to avoid blocking indefinitely on reading when incoming data is infrequent, it seems like it would be necessary to use a timeout when reading from the `TcpStream`. `std::net::TcpStream` has `set_read_timeout` for achieving this, but I can't find an equivalent for `mio::net::tcp::TcpStream`. How would I go about this? Or is there a way to share the mio `TcpStream` across multiple coroutines, avoiding the need for a timeout?

Comment: I haven't used MIO, but my (limited) understanding of async I/O is that your event loop isn't even notified unless there is data to read. Said another way, it should be *impossible* to block while trying to read — you'd just get a partial read instead. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious though!

Comment: @Shepmaster As example, imagine I have (in pseudocode):

`run_in_new_coroutine(|miocoHandle, tcpStream|{
  let stream = miocoHandle.wrap(tcpStream);
  loop{
    stream.read():
    let outVal = someMailbox.read();
    stream.write(outVal);
  })`

When it reaches `stream.read`, that coroutine will be swapped out, and won't resume until the stream can be read. If this takes 500ms, for instance, then the mailbox won't be read for 500ms, as it will only be read after `stream.read()` is completed.

Comment: That makes sense. I'd encourage you to move that into your question as it helps people like me better understand the problem.